# Emoji encoding in R

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, emoji, iso-8859-1

this is the first time I´m working with text containing Emoji character so my question might be very basic but I couldn´t find a solution yet.

I have a .txt file exported from WhatsApp on Android and sent to my PC (Windows). The data looks somethng like this:

```
chat <- c("05.10.17, 22:55 - Person A: Hey, whats up? ðŸ˜³ðŸ˜„","05.10.17, 22:55 - Person A: I heard about your problem ðŸ˜…ðŸ™„ðŸ˜‚","05.10.17, 22:56 - Person B: What? From whom?ðŸ™ˆ","05.10.17, 22:57 - Person A: Your mom...","05.10.17, 22:59 - Person B: ðŸ˜ðŸ˜„","05.10.17, 22:59 - Person B: ðŸ˜ðŸ˜„")
chat
```

.

```
[1] "05.10.17, 22:55 - Person A: Hey, whats up? ðŸ˜³ðŸ˜„"                
[2] "05.10.17, 22:55 - Person A: I heard about your problem ðŸ˜…ðŸ™„ðŸ˜‚"
[3] "05.10.17, 22:56 - Person B: What? From whom?ðŸ™ˆ"                   
[4] "05.10.17, 22:57 - Person A: Your mom..."                            
[5] "05.10.17, 22:59 - Person B: ðŸ˜ðŸ˜„"    
[6] "05.10.17, 22:59 - Person B: ðŸ˜ðŸ˜„"
```

What I want to do is replace the Emoji characters with a text-representation that is easily readable, so I want something like this:

```
[1] "05.10.17, 22:55 - Person A: Hey, whats up? [[SMILEY1]][[SMILEY2]]"                
[2] "05.10.17, 22:55 - Person A: I heard about your problem [[SMILEY2]][[SMILEY3]][[SMILEY2]]"
[3] "05.10.17, 22:56 - Person B: What? From whom?[[SMILEY3]]"                   
[4] "05.10.17, 22:57 - Person A: Your mom..."                            
[5] "05.10.17, 22:59 - Person B: [[SMILEY2]][[SMILEY2]]"    
[6] "05.10.17, 22:59 - Person B: [[SMILEY2]][[SMILEY2]]"
```

I found a dictionary online, mapping the Emojis to Text descriptions [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iorch/jakaton_feminicidios/master/data/emojis.csv), so I imported it in R:

```
# Import the List of all WhatsApp Emojis including their description
Emojis <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iorch/jakaton_feminicidios/master/data/emojis.csv"),header = T, encoding = "UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Emojis

# Pimp Description for better visibility later on
Emojis[,2] <- paste("[[Emoji:",Emojis[,2], "]]")
Emojis
```

Now I tried to replace all the matches of `Emoji[,1]` in `chat` with `Emoji [,2]`:

```
require(qdapRegex)

CleanMessage <- chat

for(i in seq_along(Emojis[,1])){

      CleanMessage <- lapply(CleanMessage,rm_default, clean = TRUE, pattern = Emojis[i,1], replacement = Emojis[i,2])
}

CleanMessage
```

However, my ouput looks exactly the same...can somebody point me to the error?

Comment: Encoding complexities may make a paste to here a non-optimal way to share the source. Take a look at https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/e89eb173ae0333f50f94fe5086fedf8b and if the basic bits work on your system, try to put your chat log somewhere that can be read in separately and I can work up an example that more meets your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post the chat log online due to confidentiality agreements. Is there any other way I could reproduce an artifical example that contains all the relevant characteristics? But I will definitly have a look at your code, thanks for the link!

Comment: The code in the link uses a chat log from the same source so it shld work but encodings are tricksy things. I totally understand not being able to share a chat log, too ;-)

Comment: how do you load the text file ? if you load it with the wrong encoding you lose data and your lookup can't work (you should include the line that loads the data in your question)